# How to switch the camera to orthographic view?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, orthographic

So the button that switches the current view from perspective/orthographic projection (Numpad 5 :) is not even there. And I want it to behave exactly the same as the main camera, so you can toggle the view with number 5 while looking through camera.

If you press number 5 while looking through camera view it cancels/jumps out of that camera view.

I could not find anything online, it might be very simple, but it's not when you don't know...

Comment: Switch the camera to "orthographic"?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the switch from "Perspective"-type to "Orthographic"-type in the camera properties dialog. There is no shortcut as far as I am aware, though

Comment: @haarigertroll That's it, I knew it has to be simple :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the camera section of the Properties window (and with camera selected as active object), you can determine the kind of [lens type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html?highlight=lens%20type#lens) you want.

> When you select Orthographic perspective objects always appear at their actual size, regardless of distance. This means that parallel lines appear parallel, and do not converge like they do with Perspective.

[image: Camera settings]

Comment: It's like music to my eyes :) Thank you very much.

Comment: If that answer did solve your issue, please consider to accept it, thanks @Robert How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour